# Split random or fixed effects into categories

Tags: panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

Consider a simple panel data model:

$$y_{it} = \alpha_{i} + X_{it}\beta + e_{it} $$

where $\alpha_{i}$ could be either random or fixed effects.

Say your data has a categorical variable $Z_{i}$ so that every individual in this sample belongs to **one and only one** category of this variable. For example, $Z_{i}$ could be the *region* where the individual lives. Assume no mobility.

**Question 1**: Is is always safe to re-write the above equation as:

$$y_{it} = \sum_{j}D_{ij}\alpha_{ij} + X_{it}\beta + e_{it} $$

where $D_{ij}$ is an indicator/dummy variable that equals one if the individual $i$ lives in region $j$?

The conceptual difference is that individuals **might** have a different unobserved effect ($\alpha$) if they would live in different regions.

**Question 2**: If this is possible, is the standard prediction of $\alpha_{i}$ from original model the same prediction for $\alpha_{ij}$? This is, is the estimation procedure to estimate these effects the same? (e.g. `predict effects , u` in Stata). My guess is yes, because each individual has just pone predictor, and since they are observed in one region only, they must coincide. But maybe adding the possibility of a wider distribution (that heterogeneity might be region specific), changes some parametric stuff, kind of like differences between conditional and joint distributions or alike.